# MATLAB generated Tikz not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab, matlab2tikz

When trying to use a `.tikz` file generated from a MATLAB script, the `.tex` file errors and is not able to build.

The `.tex` code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \setlength\figureheight{2cm} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{0.84\textwidth}
    \input{IntroGraph.tikz}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

And the IntroGraph.tikz looks like:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=5.5,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
xticklabels={{\phi^1},{\phi^2},{\phi^3 = \phi^{Opt}},{\phi^4},{\phi^5}},
xlabel={Investment Options},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=1,
ymax=8,
ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
yticklabels={{0},{},{\mu^T\phi^5},{\mu^T\phi^4},{\mu^T\phi^1},{\mu^T\phi^2},{\mu^T\phi^3},{}},
ylabel={Portfolio Expected Return},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Returns of Investement Options}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,only marks,mark=x,mark options={solid},forget plot]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{%
1   5   1.7 3.7\\
2   6   1.5 1.5\\
3   7   0.3 0.5\\
4   4   2.3 1.2\\
5   3   4.9 0.7\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: You have a lot of superscript `^` characters in there, outside math mode, it should read `$\phi^1$` etc. I can't say why this occurs, however or if `MatLab` has a switch to ensure math mode for such stuff -- I don't have MatLab on my computer

Comment: Thanks a lot, essentially all my xticklabels had to placed in $$. Now it works fine.

Comment: `yticklabels` as well ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already solved in comments.